"Unexpected strict mode reserved word" on import word in global-setup.ts in Playwright
I am trying to use Playwright with TypeScript and external libraries. When run yarn playwright test, I get:
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

   at ..\global-setup.ts:1

> 1 | import ZogBeEnv from 'env-common/src/env';
    | ^
  2 | async function globalEnvSetup() {
  3 | const testEnv = ZogBeEnv.configureDotEnv();
  4 | }

    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\temp\playwright-demo\global-setup.ts:1:1)

playwright.config.ts was generated with 'yarn create playwright' with TypeScript feature, and then added line:
globalSetup: 'global-setup.ts',

package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "playwright-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.47.2",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "env-common": "file:../env-common"
  }
}

The content of the global-setup.ts is following:
import ZogBeEnv from 'env-common/src/env';
async function globalEnvSetup() {
    const testEnv = ZogBeEnv.configureDotEnv();
}

export default globalEnvSetup;

and the env.ts:
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

export class ZogBeEnv {
     public static get TEST_ENV(): string | undefined {
         return process.env.TEST_ENV;
     }

    public static findTestEnv(): string | null {
    // REDACTED
    }

    public static configureDotEnv(): string | null {
    // REDACTED
    }
}

export default ZogBeEnv;

If I remove global-setup.ts, everything works as expected.
How can I resolve this?

Please share the source code for global-setup.ts and your sample env.

It is not really solution, but more like workaround. It looks like yarn is making troubles. Because it is not necessary for me, I moved back to npm and now everything works as expected.
